# ExpressionEngine Blog Tags

Tags: tags, blogs, expressionengine

Is there a built-in way to add tags to content in a similar way as with WordPress when using ExpressionEngine?

Comment: Note, you can post future EE questions on the beta site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Comment: You're welcome. The public beta just launched so please post EE questions there. You'll have quick help from us all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's not an EE native equivalent to WP's tags. For something similar you need to go into the 3rd party market. Here are a couple of options:

- [Tagger](http://www.devdemon.com/tagger/), free & actively maintained & supported (support requires a "developer" license of $50
- [Tag](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/tag), commercial at ~$60

Of these two I've only used Tagger. It got the job done nicely but I can't compare it to "Tag" since I haven't used it. There's another one called Taggable but I don't believe it's actively maintained or updated any more. (I would like to it but StackOverflow won't let me add more than 2 links until my rep increases.)

Comment: With either Tagger or Tag is there a way to define different types of tags. For example, can I add multiple tag fields to a single content type "Genre", "Author", "Director", etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've used both Tag and Tagger, mentioned by Erik.  I have found for my needs Tag is more that enough to do the job. Tagger adds some higher level functions, but I didn't find I needed them in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go with one of the two add-ons already listed though, to be thorough, there is also Taggable which Erik did mentioned though, couldn't link to it:

https://github.com/jamierumbelow/taggable

Comment: Notice that only Taggable supports Matrix cell type. Alas, Taggable is not maintained by Jamie anymore and suffers of preformance problems with lot of tags/entries.